# Remove UIAlerts When App Goes to Background

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uialertview

In my app I give a alert, if the user wants to confirm the offer or not. 
Now I noticed that if the user hits the home button, the alert stays there & makes my app crash if he would enter anything.
How can I remove the alert (all UIAlerts) when I go to background mode?

Kind regards,

Glenn.

Edit 1:

Basically I a making a offer page. When the user clicks OK, I am showing a UIAlert for extra confirmation. 
Now I also have functionality that when a user closes (home button) the app & restarts it, it will go to the overview page (where all the products are) and will ask the server for the data (makes the data up -to-date again.).

Normally there would be no problem with my app going into background mode. But with the functionality of refreshing the data & going to another controller it probaly gives problems. Therefore I need to be able to close all the UIAlerts still active.

Comment: from the "offer page”... dismiss the alert view [theAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]; .. when your app goes to background

Comment: & how can I check when my app goes to the background? is there a special commando to do this?

Comment: There's a notification UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification that fires when the home button is pressed; http://stackoverflow.com/a/9012734/1702413

Comment: You can try, also... In ViewDidDisappear or viewWillDisappear to dismiss the alert

Comment: Ok so what i'm doing now. 
I made a static UIAlertView that I dismisWithClickedButton when I my app goes in Background (in the AppDelegate.cs) so tanks for clarifying that! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You app crashes not because of UIAlerts but because something is going wrong. Even if you put an app in the background while showing a UIAlert, the alert stays there.

Comment: Yeah well the problem is that, if I go back to my app, I show another controller (and refresh the data there). So the alert ain't gonne work anymore ==> Makes my app crash.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

you can use it with this method in **AppDelegate.m**:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

but [Nikos M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2923572/nikos-m) was right: you should find and fix the source of this problem, but not to disguise it. there is a simplest way to show alert, check it, may be it'll help:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Some message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
```

Comment: Yeah well. I'll give a better explanation.