# How to get notification for Window Phone App entering background

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1

I know that for iOS, we can observe notification `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification` when app is terminating (see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011868/)). On windows phone, is there a similar mechanism so that I can register a event to release some app resources or saving some objects to the database?

Comment: Are you building for Silverlight or Universal?

Comment: Hello @PeterTorr-MSFT, we are building for Universal.

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle the [`Suspending` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplication.suspending.aspx). This will give you about 5-10 seconds to finish up any tasks. Just remember to take the deferral from the event args if you do any async work.

Comment: In some rare cases it won't work - the *Suspening* event won't be fired. In such cases *Window.VisibilityChanged* may be a better option, though it may have problems with running longer operations, due to app termination.

Comment: Visibility changes for things like an incoming phone call that don't actually suspend your app. Also if you move to desktop then your visibility might change for various reasons. If you have cases where Suspending isn't raised, please let me know and I'll log bugs.

Comment: You are right, seems like the case I've been facing some time ago, now, as I've checked, works just all right.

Answer (score 1):

Talked to one of my colleague just now, this may be a way to do it:

```
    protected override void OnWindowCreated(WindowCreatedEventArgs args)
    {
        args.Window.VisibilityChanged += WindowVisibilityChanged;
    }

    private void WindowVisibilityChanged(object sender, VisibilityChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Visible)
        {
            // Add the code here
        }
    }
```