# Is there a way to find out why an app entered background iOS?

Tags: ios

I want to be able to do different things depending on why an application entered background.? Ex: Home button pressed , Location services permissions .

Is there a way to find out?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the applications state via the app delegate methods. This will determine what state your application is in.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html

You can also register for Notifications which relate to those states. See this post for some further examples.

[What's the best way to detect when the app is entering the background for my view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011868/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-when-the-app-is-entering-the-background-for-my-vie)

I believe you will see different notification states for those two events.