# Detect iOS app entering background

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm working on a game for iOS coded in Swift. I've tried to find a way to detect when the app enters background mode or is interrupted for other reasons, for example a phone call but can't find anything. How do I do it?

Comment: Try looking in your application delegate.

Comment: See documentation for `UIApplicationDelegate`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to detect when the app is entering the background for my view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011868/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-when-the-app-is-entering-the-background-for-my-vie)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can add an observer to your view controller:

edit/update: **Xcode 11 • Swift 5**

**iOS13 or later**

```
UIScene.willDeactivateNotification
```

**iOS12 or earlier**

```
UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification
```

---

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willResignActive), name: UIScene.willDeactivateNotification, object: nil)
} else {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willResignActive), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
}
```

and add a selector method to your view controller that will be executed when your app receives that notification:

```
@objc func willResignActive(_ notification: Notification) {
    // code to execute
}
```

Comment: Thanks! For **Swift 4**, add `@objc` before `func`.

Comment: For Swift 4.2, use `name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification`.

Comment: this method can be triggered if u receive an SMS too . https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622950-applicationwillresignactive . the method is actually didEnterBackgroundNotification

Comment: It should be noted that this no longer works for apps under iOS 13 unless the app has opted out of using scenes.

Comment: @rmaddy If so can you please suggest how it should be tackled ? Do I need Xcode 11 for the same ?

Comment: @SharadChauhan See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57488057/view-controller-responds-to-app-delegate-notifications-in-ios-12-but-not-in-ios

Answer (score 33):

In **swift 5.x**: To observe app enters **background** event, add this code to your **viewDidLoad()** method.

```
    let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToBackground), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)

    @objc func appMovedToBackground() {
        // do whatever event you want
    }
```

you have to use `UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification`.
If you want to observe if app came to **foreground** event, use `UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification`

So, the full code will be:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToBackground), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
    
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appCameToForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
 @objc func appMovedToBackground() {
    print("app enters background")
}

@objc func appCameToForeground() {
    print("app enters foreground")
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that this no longer works for apps under iOS 13 unless the app has opted out of using scenes.

Answer (score 9):

**Swift3**

```
let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToBackground), name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)


func appMovedToBackground() {
    print("App moved to background!")
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that this no longer works for apps under iOS 13 unless the app has opted out of using scenes.

Answer (score 7):

To detect the app enters background, you can check in the appDelegate.m
find the application delegate method

> applicationDidEnterBackground

This method will get called, once the app enters background.

Comment: This would only tell you when the app had already entered the background - there would be some latency between this happening, and the method being called.

Comment: Yes, exactly  applicationWillResignActive possible answer, +1 @AlexBlundell : Good work.

Comment: It should be noted that this no longer works for apps under iOS 13 unless the app has opted out of using scenes.

Answer (score 7):

**SwiftUI**

From background

```
Text("Hello, World!")
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)) { _ in
    print("To the foreground!")
}
```

To the background

```
Text("Hello, World!")
    .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification)) { _ in
        print("To the background!")
    }
```

Comment: `UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification` is not appropriate for app entering background. It can trigger even when you receive phone call.

Answer (score 4):

For **SwiftUI** you can use:

```swift
YourView()
 .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIScene.willDeactivateNotification)) { _ in
     //...
 }
```

Comment: This is a great answer, you know how can i keep my download when app in background?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the delegate methods defined in your instance of `UIApplicationDeletegate` (called `AppDelegate.m` by default). Specifically the following would be useful:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

> This method is called to let your app know that it is about to move from the active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the app and it begins the transition to the background state. An app in the inactive state continues to run but does not dispatch incoming events to responders.

Taken from the Apple Documentation - [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ar#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive:)

Comment: It should be noted that this no longer works for apps under iOS 13 unless the app has opted out of using scenes.