# Can't stop timer in background

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I have `timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3.0, target: self, selector: "get", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)` in `FirstVC` and `var timer: NSTimer?` out of class(I mean declared globally).

Then I want call `timer?.invalidate()` in `applicationDidEnterBackground` or `applicationWillResignActive` in `AppDelegate`, but it doesn't work.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: no need to declare it globally. add an observer for applicationWillResignActive notification at your view controller and invalidate it there

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34745677/2303865