# Xamarin.iOS coreML Get Prediction null reference error in background mode

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, coreml

model.GetPrediction method returns a null object when the iOS app is running in background mode. The method return correct predictions when app is in foreground. Has anyone else come across this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things:

You have very limited time to execute arbitrary code when the app is  `Backgrounded`.

- You can check `BackgroundTimeRemaining` to determine how much time you have left.
- You have to perform your predictions within a `BeginBackgroundTask` action

The foregrounded app (including Springboard) has priority over the GPU.

- The foregrounded app GPU processing will not be interrupted to perform your background task-based prediction.
- You can request predictions to use the CPU (`UsesCpuOnly`) by supplying the  `MLPredictionOptions` to your prediction call.

> Your model should be restricted to the CPU **if it might run in the background** or if your app has other GPU intensive tasks.

re: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlpredictionoptions/2921288-usescpuonly?language=objc

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Enabling the UsesCpuOnly option returns valid predictions in the background.

Comment: The `usesCPUOnly` flag was the solution for us as well. Posted sample code of how to do it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48480610/error-computing-nn-outputs-error