# How do I detect a swipe to view notifications or control panel

Tags: ios, swift

I notice that my app backgrounds when I swipe from the top or bottom of my screen to view notifications or control panel. How can I detect when these events happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect iOS app entering background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744783/detect-ios-app-entering-background)

Answer (score 1):

When you swipe to view the notifications panel, the app doesn't remain active. This method is fired up when the app loses focus.
In your AppDelegate file, add the following method:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
}
```

To detect when the notification panel is removed i.e. swiped up, use

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
}
```