# Cover top view controller when app enters background

Tags: ios, swift

When an app goes into the background, I want to put a blur view in a xib file (so it can be customized) on top of my top view controller so that users can't see the content of my app when using multitasking. How would I do that? I tried a bunch of stuff with the root view controller but it didn't work. I know I need to use these delegate methods but I am not sure exactly how to get the top view controller and put a view on top of it. I am using tab bar controller with a bunch of navigation controllers.

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
}
```

and

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
}
```

When the app is opened again, I obviously want to get rid of that blur view but I would also like to use Face/Touch ID to give access. I assume this is pretty straight forward using LocalAuthentication.

Comment: One way to do that is creating a XIB that will cover entire screen, you can design it as you want with blur, images etc, then you instantiate and call it in your window to cover as a modal

Comment: yes exactly but how would I call it and put it over the current vc in the app delegate? I know how to set it up and design it and all.

Comment: @NevinJethmalani Detect iOS app entering background https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744783/detect-ios-app-entering-background/34745677#34745677

Answer (score 9):

In `AppDelegate.swift` class, please try this code snippet,

```
let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView()

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    self.visualEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
if !self.visualEffectView.isDescendant(of: self.window!) {
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
    self.visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    self.visualEffectView.frame = (self.window?.bounds)!
    self.window?.addSubview(self.visualEffectView)
   }
}
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    self.visualEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

And yes you are correct about `Face ID/Touch ID` using `LocalAuthentication`, you may want to use `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` to detect if the app came to the foreground and show the authentication alert accordingly. I think you need to add this behavior to your `ViewController`.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than adding and removing it from the superview every time, you could leave it and change the effect as needed.  Add the following to your `AppDelegate`:

```
let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: nil)

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    if !self.visualEffectView.isDescendant(of: self.window!) {
         self.window?.addSubview(self.visualEffectView)
    }
    self.visualEffectView.frame = (self.window?.bounds)!

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.visualEffectView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
    }

}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.visualEffectView.effect = nil
    }
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.visualEffectView.effect = nil
    }    
}
```

This would have the added benefit of you being able to fade the effect in and out.

Comment: In my case, current view become not responsive, after `visualEffectView.effect = nil`

Comment: your code make user can not interact with screen after  applicationDidBecomeActive

Answer (score 0):

> you can do this to add animation and must have to remove fromsuperview to access other view.if you make self.visualEffectsView = nil it will not allow to access otherview.

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
  self.visualEffectsView.alpha = 0.0
}) { _ in
  self.visualEffectsView.removeFromSuperview()
}
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
window?.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(visualEffectsView)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
  self.visualEffectsView.alpha = 1.0
})
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To call a view controller from appDelegate you can use this method

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vcMainView: YourVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourVC") as! YourVC
    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(vcMainView, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Don't forget to set your VC identifier in your Identity Inspector - Identity section

Comment: I'm not the OP, but your code is not the answer to the question OP asked. Your answer is from the same category of "go google it"...

Comment: really ?? Just think a little and add one line, just one line and get your result. I'm trying to help and SO is taken of people trying to outsource their dev without thinking. Here is your line: `self.window?.rootViewController?.present(vcMainView, animated: true, completion: nil)`