# How pause a timer when app disappear due to call mobile reception?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

Do you know how I can pause (or stop) my timer when my app stop and disappear due to call mobile reception ?

is it method in AppDelegate ?

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744783/detect-ios-app-entering-background to have your view controller with the timer know when the app becomes inactive. Also register to know when the app becomes active again.

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to the `willResignActiveNotification` notification in `NotificationCenter` and run code when that happens. You can read up on it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622973-willresignactivenotification).