# NSURLSession when app goes into background or iOS looses network connectivity

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, ios10

What happens to an *ephemeral* `NSURLSession` of type *data task* when an app switches from the foreground or iOS looses network connectivity?

In particular, will its `NSURLSessionDelegate` be notified, or do I have to observe at the level of `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` ([as well as](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9012734/1789384) `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification`) and `kReachabilityChangedNotification` respectively, if I don't want the `NSURLSession` to disappear "silently".

Comment: The task will end up with an error when appropriate, isn't that enough for you?

Comment: @jcaron So are you saying that the delegate's `URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:` will always be called with `error != nil` when one of the two scenarios occurs?

Comment: I'm not certain just going to background will necessarily abort the transfer (I wouldn't be surprised if it kept on running for at least a few seconds, so that you can come back to the app and continue as if nothing happened – this is especially true for resigning active rather than actually going to background), though I haven't tested it. Likewise, depending on the exact "connectivity loss" scenario (actually losing the network/packet loss), the transfer may try to continue as well. But I'm quite confident that if the transfer is finally aborted, you'll get the error reported. Just test it!